# Program to check if one string is contained cyclic in the other one

Tags: c++, string

doing some exrecises for upcoming test. a bit stuck in this one.

"Write a program that asks the user for two strings and checks and prints a message if the second string is **contained cyclic** in the first string. The cyclic containment means that either the second string appears normally within the first string or the second string appears so that its prefix appears at the end of the first string and the continuation appears at the beginning of the first string".

You can assume that the strings contain only lowercase letters.
String functions are only allowed are : strlen, strcpy, strcmp, strcat

for example:

String A: iti**sanic**eday
String B: **sanic**

Is a regular occurrence

String A: **it**isanice**day**
String B: **dayit**

It's a cyclic occurence.

what I did so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
#define Max 128

int isCyclic(char* str1, char* str2);

int main()
{
    char* str1 = new char[Max];
    char* str2 = new char[Max];

    cout << "Please enter two strings:" << endl;

    cin >> str1 >> str2;

    cout << isCyclic(str1, str2) << endl;


    delete[] str1;
    delete[] str2;
}

int isCyclic(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    int s1 = strlen(str1);
    int s2 = strlen(str2);

    if (s1!=s2) // if string size is diffrent - they are not contained cyclic
    {
        return 0;
    }


}
```

Comment: `if (s1!=s2)` doesn't do what you think it does in multiple manners. You are comparing two pointers, not _`string`_ s. Use the `std::string` class instead of raw `char*` c-style pointers.

Comment: can't, didnt study this way @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: That's the idiomatic way to do in c++. Using `std::string` would make your chances to get a job in industry way better. So why aren't you learning c++?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I understand but that's how we study in uni

Comment: Well, to compare raw c-style strings use `strcmp()`. As mentioned you just compare two pointer values, which won't do what you want to achieve,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need two loops, first one over string 1 which is our starting point in string 1 for comparison and second one over string 2 which will be matched to string 1 in a cyclic way. If we reach the end of string 1 and still some characters are left in string 2 then cycle through string 1 starting from index 0.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

// Should be avoided in general. Use scope resolution instead.
using namespace std;

char* isCyclic(char* s1, char* s2){
    int s1_size = strlen(s1);
    int s2_size = strlen(s2);

    // s1 must contain s2
    if(s2_size > s1_size)
        return "No Occurence";


    for(int i = 0; i < s1_size; i++){
        int current = i;
        // Boolean to track if we are currently cycling through s1
        bool inCycle = false;
        int j = 0;
        for(; j < s2_size; j++, current++){
            // character wise comparision
            if(s2[j] != s1[current])
                break;
            if(! inCycle){
                // start from first. Note that we are setting current = -1.
                // as we will be incrementing it in the for loop.
                if(current == s1_size - 1 && j < s2_size - 1){
                    current = -1;
                    inCycle = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if(j == s2_size){
            if(inCycle)
                return "cyclic";
            else
                return "regular";
        }
    }

    return "No Occurence";
}


int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");

    char* s1 = "itisaniceday";
    char* s2 = "dayitis";

    cout<<"Occurence Type: "<<isCyclic(s1, s2)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the second part of the problem (cyclic part). I simply go through all of the characters in the first string and checked if they are the beginning of a cyclic appearance of the second string.
To check that I used % (the modolu operation) if you don't know what it dose then you really need to learn it now.
Also I used bool instead of int because numbers are confusing (and cursed).

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string.h>
    using namespace std;
    #define Max 128

    bool isCyclic(char* str1, char* str2);
    bool isCyclic(char* str1, char* str2,int start);

    int main()
    {
        char* str1 = new char[Max];
        char* str2 = new char[Max];
        cout << "Please enter two strings:" << endl;
        cin >> str1 >> str2;
        cout << isCyclic(str1, str2) << endl;
        delete[] str1;
        delete[] str2;
    }
    bool isCyclic(char* str1, char* str2)   {
            for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str1); i++)   {
                    if(str1[i] == str2[0] && isCyclic(str1,str2,i)) {
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
    }

    bool isCyclic(char* str1, char* str2,int start)
    {
            int containingStrLen = strlen(str1);
            for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str2); i++)   {
                    if(str1[(start + i)%containingStrLen] != str2[i])       {
                            return false;
                    }
            }
            return true;
    }
```

There are some things missing in this code still:

1) The first part of the problem (it can easily be derived from this code).

2) Some size validation such as making sure that str1 is bigger then str2 before using is cyclic. And that the strings are smaller then Max (I assume).

3) A proper result print.

Good luck in your exam :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple trick : if you duplicate the string's prefix at its own end, the problem becomes a straight substring search as a cyclic match would be recomposed at the end. It also handles the corner case where the substring loops back on itself, such as `"looploop"` inside of `"loop"`.

So here's how you'd do it in broken C-ish dialect:

```
bool containsCyclic(char const *string, char const *substring) {
    std::size_t const stringLen = std::strlen(string);
    std::size_t const substringLen = std::strlen(substring);

    // Too long a substring wouldn't fit in the string
    if(substringLen > 2 * stringLen)
        return false;

    // Concatenate `string` with its own substring-long prefix
    char *const loopedString = new char[stringLen + substringLen + 1];
    std::strcpy(loopedString, string);

    { // Partial reimplementation of std::strncpy(loopedString, string, substringLen)
        char const *src = string;
        char *dest = loopedString +  stringLen;
        for(std::size_t count = 0; count < substringLen; ++count)
            *dest++ = *src++;

        *dest = '\0';
    }

    { // Partial and naïve reimplementation of std::strstr(loopedString, substring)
        for(char const *start = loopedString; start < loopedString + stringLen; ++start) {
            // Check if substring is present at this offset
            char const *s1 = start;
            char const *s2 = substring;

            while(*s2 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
                ++s1, ++s2;

            if(*s2 == '\0') {
                // We found a complete match of substring inside loopedString
                delete[] loopedString;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // No match found
    delete[] loopedString;
    return false;
}
```

And just for kicks, here it is in C++:

```
bool containsCyclicCpp(std::string const &string, std::string const &substring) {
    std::string const loopedString = string + string.substr(0, substring.size());
    return loopedString.find(substring) != std::string::npos;
}
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2497d7c6bea54233) (with tests!)